# How to simplify this Javascript File

Tags: javascript, php, file

I have a script such as this one:

```
<span>Famous Quote:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script language="JavaScript">
var Quotation=new Array() // do not change this!
Quotation[0] = "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.";
Quotation[1] = "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.";
Quotation[2] = "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.";
Quotation[3] = "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.";
Quotation[4] = "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.";
Quotation[5] = "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.";
Quotation[6] = "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.";
Quotation[7] = "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.";
Quotation[8] = "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.";
Quotation[9] = "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.";
Quotation[10] = "Things are only impossible until they're not.";
var Q = Quotation.length;
var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
function showQuotation(){document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]);}
showQuotation();
</script>
```

How can I put the quotations in their own file, rather than the source code? Here is an example: http://mydomain.go/quote.js

Comment: `var Quotation=new Array()` really cant change? just put it inside that `Quotation` array.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your response.

Comment: What are you doing with accepting? You can to accept one answer only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be better:

```
var Quotation=
[
    "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.",
    "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.",
    "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.",
    "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.",
    "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.",
    "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.",
    "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.",
    "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.",
    "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.",
    "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.",
    "Things are only impossible until they're not."
]
```

You could put that in a separate script if you really wanted to. Beyond that, there isn't any 'simple' way to improve the script.

Edit:

Put it in a separate file, then add a script tag:

```
<script src="whatever.js"></script>
```

Then you will have access to `Quotation` in your main file.

Comment: Thanks! Does the rest of coding remain the same? var Q = Quotation.length;
var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
function showQuotation(){document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]);}
showQuotation();

Comment: I recommend to change your randomization. See my answer.

Comment: yeah, everything else should still work as before. Just add the script tag earlier in the file.

Answer (score 3):

Well that is array , you can go like this

```
var Quotation=["Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.","Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.",... and so on]
```

Your second way could be maintaining XML, Which will give you the freedom to expand your Quotations list in fututre.

Create an xml like quot.xml And access it via js

```
<QuotList>
 <quotation>Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.</quotation>
 <quotation>Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces</quotation>
</QuotList>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include a file **quotes.js** in HTML file.

HTML Part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="quote.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>Famous Quote:

        <script language="JavaScript">
            console.log(Quotation);
            var Q = Quotation.length;
            var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
            function showQuotation(){document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]);}
            showQuotation();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: Create a new file **quote.js** and put this code in a file, And this file is already included in HTML page.

```
var Quotation=
[
    "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.",
    "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.",
    "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.",
    "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.",
    "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.",
    "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.",
    "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.",
    "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.",
    "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.",
    "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.",
    "Things are only impossible until they're not."
]
```

Answer (score 2):

create a file, let's call it quotes.js and add this:

```
var Quotation=[
"Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.",
"Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.",
"Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.",
"Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.",
"Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.",
"Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.",
"O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.",
"Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.",
"Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.",
"Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.",
"Things are only impossible until they're not."
];
```

no you can include this file in your main script by

```
<script src="path/to/quotes.js"></script>
```

and do whatever you want with it from here:

```
<script>
var Q = Quotation.length;
var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
function showQuotation(){document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]);}
showQuotation();
</script>
```

---

NOTE:

Since html5 you don't need those javascript and text/javascript in your script tags any more, as they are default for the script tag now.

NOTE2:

You shouldn't use document.write in production!

Answer (score 2):

First, simplify array declaration:

```
var Q = [
  "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.",
  "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces."
];
```

Then, your random is not equable. Use `Math.floor(Math.random()*Q)` instead;

```
document.write(Q[Math.floor(Math.random()*Q.length)]);
```

Then move array declaration into own js file(`quotes.js`) and just include in by:

```
<script src="quotes.js"></script>
```

And that's all:

```
<script src="quotes.js"></script>
document.write(Q[Math.floor(Math.random()*Q.length)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

here's how I would do that code...

```js
var quotes = [
"Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.",
"Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.",
"Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.",
"Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.",
"Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.",
"Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.",
"O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.",
"Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.",
"Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.",
"Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.",
"Things are only impossible until they're not."
];

var randQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];

document.write(randQuote);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a module loader to split up your code into different files.

`index.html` contents:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.15/require.js"></script>
```

`scripts/main.js` contents:

```
require(['quotations'], function (quotations) {
    var whichQuotation = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotations.length);
    function showQuotation(){
        document.write(quotations[whichQuotation]);
    }
    showQuotation();
});
```

`scripts/quotations.js` contents:

```
define(function () {
    return [
        "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.",
        "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.",
        "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.",
        "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.",
        "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.",
        "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.",
        "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.",
        "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.",
        "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.",
        "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.",
        "Things are only impossible until they're not."
    ];
});
```

JavaScript does not have an `import` statement. Splitting the code across `<script>` tags is difficult because variables like your `Quotation` become global variables. So if anyone else working on your website tries to define a variable called `Quotation`, you're both screwed. Using a module loader allows you to share the quotation list without consuming that variable.

I also fixed your random index algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This worked great! Thanks everyone!

```js
var quotes = [
"Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.",
"Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.",
"Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.",
"Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.",
"Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.",
"Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.",
"O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.",
"Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.",
"Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.",
"Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.",
"Things are only impossible until they're not."
];

var randQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];

document.write(randQuote);
```